# understanding the solution to a particular differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

so I ran across this problem:

> $(3x^2+1)y' -2xy = 6x$

I solved it by integrating factor $ e^{\int\frac{-2x}{3x^2+1} dx}$

.

.

.

$\int D[(3x^2+1)^{\frac{-1}{3}}y] = \int 6x(3x^2+1)^{\frac{-4}{3}} dx$

.

.

.

$(3x^2+1)^{\frac{-1}{3}}y = -3(3x^2+1)^{\frac{-1}{3}} + C$

$y = -3 + C(3x^2+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

my question is interpreting the solution $y=-3 + C(3x^2+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$. So I understand why the integrating factor method works in solving the problem. Why did the answer come out so simple after doing so much work? Could I have solved it 'faster?'

Comment: You forgot the constant  before last step where you cancelled stuff: 

$$(3x^2+1)^{\frac{-1}{3}}y = -3(3x^2+1)^{\frac{-1}{3}} + C$$

Comment: where should the constant go?

Comment: Just after we perform the integration, we add the integrating constant. Otherwise, you see that $y$ is a family of curves and not just a constant.

Comment: You add in the constant immediately after you integrate, not just at the end.

Comment: Once you know $y=-3$ is the solution, and notice that the equation is linear, then $y+3$ would be the solution of the *homogenous* part $(3x^2+1)\frac{dy}{dx}-2xy=0$. This in turn is an equation which admits separation of variables $\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{2xdx}{3x^2+1}$. Maybe then you can just skip mentioning *how* you found out $y=-3$ was a solution, and just write "Notice that $y=3$ is a solution etc. etc."...

Comment: I see that now you have added the constant and you would further like to delete the part "why did the answer come out so simple?" As for solving the DE faster, this method is the standard method to solve these kinds of DEs.

Comment: okay, thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform the equation simply as
$$
(3x^2+1)y'=2x(y+3)
\\~\\
y'=\frac{2x}{3x^2+1}(y+3)
$$
This is a separable equation and the case of the constant solution $y=-3$ appears directly as the one to exclude for performing the separation of variables. Then continue
$$
\int\frac{dy}{y+3}=\int\frac{2x\,dx}{3x^2+1}.
$$

Comment: oh okay, thank you, that makes it so much clear!